# Post logo in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

I want to publish a logo in the middle of this website

I have attached a picture to understand where they want to publish

http://i60.tinypic.com/2nuslzl.png

How can I publish such a logo? Must create a separate div in header.php and align it in the middle?

Is there any widget "custom HTML" in which public code and resolve these things?

I changed this themplate for Wordpress Twenty Fourteen

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
<div id="logo-theme">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                             <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/LOGO.png'; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
                        </a>
</div>
```

CODE CSS:

```
 #logo-theme
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please learn [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (like a reduced test case, hosted as a code snippet or on JSfiddle), so that we can help you. For starters, you can post the raw HTML output and the relevant CSS. Linking to external sites are typically discouraged as they are subjected to link rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add element width for using margin: 0 auto;

```
#logo-theme {
margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
display: block;
width:220px; //Logo Width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to give some CSS to the logo.

```
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
```

The above CSS will bring the logo image to the center.
You can change the top margin to any number, since you want it somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

So you the HTML would look like

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Image description" id="logo" />
```

And then the CSS would be

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: solved ... in your opinion now looks well centered for all resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the size of the image you want to do this with, it's pretty simple. Just use some margins and positioning.

First, display the image as a `block`, then set the width. Give it a `postion:relative;` and `top:50%`. This is the first step in getting it to center vertically. Then just set the margin to `margin:-100px auto 0`. The `-100px` completes the vertical centering, and the `auto` makes it center horizontally.

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -100px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my post instead of #div img..in would have to put img # logo-theme img {}?

Comment: solved ... in your opinion now looks well centered for all resolutions?

Comment: Yes, mine will stay centered as long as the size of the image doesn't change. With the code you added, you would just target the anchor instead of the image.